# appendChild of objects containing javascript attributes

Tags: javascript, attributes, appendchild

i have this Javascript function

```
function webit(thumb){
    webi = document.createElement("img");
    webi.alt=thumb.id.replace("t", "");
    webi.id = "w"+webi.alt;
    webi.className = "web";
    webi.src= thumb.src.replace("thm","web");
    webi.height=233;
    webi.onclick='alert()';
    document.body.appendChild(webi);
}
```

which is supposed to embed a larger version of a thumbnail image the end of the document. It works fine *except* that any javascript function ( ie onXXX) stays resolutely null. This seems to be no matter which JS function i use and afaict any thing i try to set it to.

The above example uses

```
    webi.onclick='alert()';
```

which fails leaving onclick null, though all the other statements succeed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When in javascript the [.onclick](http://mdn.beonex.com/en/DOM/element.onclick.html#Syntax) property expects a function not a string

```
webi.onclick=function(){ alert(); };
```

You could also use the [addEventListener](http://mdn.beonex.com/en/DOM/element.addEventListener.html) method to set an event handler

```
webi.addEventListener("click",function(){ alert(); });
```

Comment: Thanks @PatrickEvans! Both change onclick ... but only the **addEventListener** version seems effective at adding an onclick event.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems, you are giving quotes to `alert` & `onclick` requires a function that can be called after clicking on it, you should not call the assigned function.

```
webi.onclick=function(){alert()};
```

Answer (score 0):

You might consider declaring webi as var. Without "var", you implicitly defined window.webi, and it will introduce memory leaks.
var webi = document.createElement("img");
In addition, jQuery is usually a better choice than raw js/browser API.